# Why mayavi does not show figure?

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have just installed vtk, mayavi. Then I ran an example, but nothing showed. Can you tell me how to show the figure?

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import vtk
x, y, z, value = np.random.random((4, 40))
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation, [see here](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_running_scripts.html), you need to call `mlab.show()` when running such a script after your `mlab.points3d()`.

Comment: Even then it is not coming up